# Microk8s snap broken

Tags: snap, microk8s

I am trying to get Microk8s to work using snap. When I run any snap command related to microk8s, I get the following error message:

```
error : cannot perform the following tasks:
- Arrêter les services du paquet Snap "microk8s" ([stop snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet.service] failed with exit status 5: Failed to stop snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet.service: Unit snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet.service not loaded.
)
```

(*Arrêter les services du paquet* mean *Stop services of package*).

I get the exact same message when I try to start Microk8s, remove the Snap package, or pretty much anything else. So, not only I can’t use it, I can’t even uninstall it. Can anyone help?

Snap version:

```
snap       2.39.3
snapd      2.39.3
series     16
linuxmint  19.1
kernel     4.18.0-25-generic
```

Comment: Hi! What is the result of `snap version`? Can you please paste that? Do any other snaps install, like can you `snap install hello-world`?

Comment: Added output of `snap version`. Yes, `snap install hello-world` works.

Comment: OK, I reverted the edit and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had pasted a line in the Microk8s configuration that was supposed to enable it to work by changing iptables settings. Except it called iptables instead of /bin/iptables, which didn’t work for me. Fixed. Now, why this prevented (for example) from uninstalling the snap is beyond me.